# Recursive function ignoring exclusion condition

Tags: python, loops, recursion

I'm probably being thick, but I'm confused about why this recursive function is ignoring the exclusion condition I've provided.

In the code below, I take a base value, and get a list of corresponding values from another function. Each value in the list needs to be processed, and needs its own list of corresponding values fetched, for which the same process occurs until all relevant values have been processed.

To avoid processing any values twice, I've added a condition within `the_loop` that is meant to only process values that haven't already been processed. Every time a value is processed, it's added to the exclusion list, and should skip the loop.

```
def the_recursive_func(key):
   values = get_values(key) # values is a list of numbers
   processed_values = {}

   def the_loop(list_of_values):
      not_processed = [v for v in list_of_values if v not in processed_values.keys()]

      for v in not_processed:
          processed = process_value(v)
          processed_values[v] = processed
          new_values_list = get_values(v)
          the_loop(new_values_list)

   the_loop(values)
   return processed_values
```

Instead, I'm processing a lot of values twice. I'm struggling to see where this is going wrong.
If I change the for loop to:

```
      for v in not_processed:
          if v in processed_values.keys():
             continue
          processed = process_value(v)
          processed_values[v] = processed
          new_values_list = get_values(v)
          the_loop(new_values_list)
```

Then I get the results I'm looking for, but A) this is spaghetti, and B) I'm missing something fundamental in why the initial code doesn't work.

Comment: In the initial code, you exclude values before you start adding any. Plus, I might be missing something, but you aren't even using `not_processed`.

Comment: You're looping over `list_of_values`, not `not_processed`.

Comment: FYI, `v not in processed_values.keys()` can be simplified to just `v not in processed_values` since `in` just checks the keys.

Comment: @iz_ @Barmar that's my mistake, I've edited the post - I am indeed iterating over `not_processed`.

@iz_ that's by design - the new list may contain more values than I mean to process

Comment: Noted, thanks @Barmar!

Comment: `not_processed` doesn't change during the loop. Do you need to exclude items that are processed by previous loop iterations?

Comment: @mbake I have no way to test the code (maybe try creating a [mcve]), but try changing `not_processed` to a generator (replace `[... for ... in ... if ...]` with `(... for ... in ... if ...)`) and see what that does for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only excluding values at the beginning of the function. If you need to exclude values that are processed in earlier iterations of the loop (possibly in the recursion), you need to do the test each time through the loop.

```
    def the_loop(list_of_values):
        for v in list_of_values:
            if v in processed_values:
                continue
            processed = process_value(v)
            processed_values[v] = processed
            new_values_list = get_values(v)
            the_loop(new_values_list)
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar! You're right, I was misunderstanding the sequence of events here. Really appreciate the help.